How do you get a Vec of coefficients of a polynomial in PARI/GP?
Say I have a polynomial variable:
gp > p = -41*z^6 + 102*z^5 - 105*z^4 + 60*z^3 - 15*z^2 + 6*z + 1
%1 = -41*z^6 + 102*z^5 - 105*z^4 + 60*z^3 - 15*z^2 + 6*z + 1

How do I get a vector of the coefficients?

Looks like you can simply do Vec(p):
gp > p = -41*z^6 + 102*z^5 - 105*z^4 + 60*z^3 - 15*z^2 + 6*z + 1
%1 = -41*z^6 + 102*z^5 - 105*z^4 + 60*z^3 - 15*z^2 + 6*z + 1
gp > v = Vec(p)
%2 = [-41, 102, -105, 60, -15, 6, 1]

And the inverse is done via Pol:
gp > Pol(v, z)
%3 = -41*z^6 + 102*z^5 - 105*z^4 + 60*z^3 - 15*z^2 + 6*z + 1

